# .net web api spa - access AuthenticationProperties in GetUserInfo

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application, owin

I created a new project using Knockout SPA VS template.

in the `AccountController` there is a method `GetExternalLogin`, which has the following code towards the end:

```cs
Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
ClaimsIdentity cookieIdentity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
AuthenticationProperties properties = ApplicationOAuthProvider.CreateProperties(user.UserName);
Authentication.SignIn(properties, oAuthIdentity, cookieIdentity);
```

I modified method `CreateProperties` to return some extra data:

```cs
IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "userId", "1" },
    { "userName", userName },
    { "isActivated", "false" },
    { "accountType", "2" }
};
return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
```

This is not a sensitive data and I want this data to be available any time an action `GetUserInfo()` is called.

```cs
[HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]
[Route("UserInfo")]
public UserInfoViewModel GetUserInfo()
{
    ExternalLoginData externalLogin = ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);

    return new UserInfoViewModel
    {
        UserName = User.Identity.GetUserName(),
        HasRegistered = externalLogin == null,
        LoginProvider = externalLogin != null ? externalLogin.LoginProvider : null
        // I want to add custom data here
    };
}
```

Am I wrong in assuming that I can somehow retrieve that data in that method?

Comment: You can try to access the `AuthenticationProperties` from the  `Athentication.AuthenticationResponseGrant` so with `AuthenticationProperties properties = Authentication.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Properties;`

Comment: `Authentication.AuthenticationResponseGrant` is null when `GetUserInfo()` is called. Am I still missing something?

Comment: Why not add those to the claims collection?  Usually upon authentication of an application, you would add all application claims for that user to the collection.

Comment: @William, could you show some code please? I thought that the object I modified is there specifically to address my problem

Comment: My understanding (could be very wrong) is the AuthenticationProperties is returned in the json response, and the values are not in the bearer token.  So it would only be there on the initial login return.  When you call out to GetUserInfo passing the token for authentication, the values wouldnt be there and you would have to add the values to UserInfoViewModel manually if you needed them which is ok too.  If you added the values to the claims upon authenticaiton, they would be in the token and available on every call because it would be in the User.Identity.Claims (didnt check syntax)

Comment: Same concept applies for the cookie vs bearer.

Comment: @William, thanks, your suggestion to put this info into Claims worked perfectly.